# How to display contents of checkboxes field

Tags: channel-entries, channel-fields

Hello i'am using ExpressionEngine v3.3.4 for a short time.

I have field group with field 'shop_item_product_sizes'. (attachment) Is it possible to dynamically print only selected checkboxes as select to my template? [http://imgur.com/kBMmhH4](https://imgur.com/kBMmhH4)

expected result (based on attachment)

```
<select>
    <option>Select size</option>
    <option>M</option>
    <option>XL</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a standard Checkboxes field, so you just need to [follow the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/select.html#multiple-items).

```
{if shop_item_product_sizes}
<select name="sizes">
    <option>Select size</option>
    {shop_item_product_sizes}
    <option value="{item}">{item}</option>
    {/shop_item_product_sizes}
</select>
{/if}
```